# (Sqoop-import) ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 9

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

when I type the command :

```
./sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop2 -table sqeep2 -m 1 -hive-import
```

when execute this command :

```
hadoop@dewi:/opt/sqoop/bin$ ./sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop2 -table sqeep2 -m 1 -hive-import
12/06/20 10:00:44 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
12/06/20 10:00:44 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
12/06/20 10:00:44 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
12/06/20 10:00:45 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sqeep2` AS t LIMIT 1
12/06/20 10:00:45 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sqeep2` AS t LIMIT 1
12/06/20 10:00:45 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_HOME is /opt/hadoop
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/dedd7d201dfca40c5cd5dee4919e0487/sqeep2.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
12/06/20 10:00:46 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/dedd7d201dfca40c5cd5dee4919e0487/sqeep2.jar
12/06/20 10:00:46 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
12/06/20 10:00:46 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
12/06/20 10:00:46 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
12/06/20 10:00:46 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
12/06/20 10:00:46 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of sqeep2
12/06/20 10:00:46 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sqeep2` AS t LIMIT 1
12/06/20 10:00:46 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
12/06/20 10:00:46 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201206200849_0006
12/06/20 10:00:47 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/06/20 10:00:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201206200849_0006
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 11
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=4255
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=106
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=41020
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=3
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=3
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=87
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 6.5932 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 3 records.
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sqeep2` AS t LIMIT 1
12/06/20 10:00:53 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `sqeep2` AS t LIMIT 1
12/06/20 10:00:53 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column price had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
12/06/20 10:00:53 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column design_date had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive
12/06/20 10:00:54 INFO hive.HiveImport: Hive history file=/tmp/hadoop/hive_job_log_hadoop_201206201000_695261712.txt
12/06/20 10:01:00 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException File file:/user/hive/warehouse/sqeep2 does not exist.)
12/06/20 10:01:00 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
12/06/20 10:01:00 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 9
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:326)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:276)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:218)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:362)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:423)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:180)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:228)

hadoop@dewi:/opt/sqoop/bin$
```

what's wrong with my sqoop command ?

Please any solution :)
Thank's

Answer (score 3):

I had modified hive-site.xml so that
the value of `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` is `/home/hadoop/data/hive/warehouse`.

Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your sqoop syntax is wrong, two dashes before tool-specific arguments.  Try:

> ./sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sqoop2 --table sqeep2 -m 1 --hive-import

Answer (score 0):

Does the table sqeep2 exist?

`12/06/20 10:01:00 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException File file:/user/hive/warehouse/sqeep2 does not exist.)`

Comment: wether /user/hive/warehouse also affect the sqoop-import table? 

thank's :)

Comment: Not sure i understand your question

Comment: I'm sorry, in the above case, in fact I have yet to make a directory to its warehouse. whether it also has an effect?

Comment: I'm sure it is reliant on the warehouse directory existing, and the table probably has to be created too (which will create the directory to hold the metadata)

Comment: but I have problem when I create directory /warehouse always failed ?
see http://pastebin.com/7dZbpgad
how?

Comment: Does your current user have permissions to create a folder in the /user/hive HDFS folder?

Comment: Also, make sure the hadoop namenode and datanode are running before you perform this operation (You can use `jps` to do so). Check the hadoop logs to figure out the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Step - 1: Set your .bashrc file $HADOOP_HOME , $HIVE_HOME , $SQOOP_HOME

Step - 2: Start the hiveserver & metastore

```
      bin/hive --service hiveserver
      bin/hive --service metastore
```

Try this Command's

Answer (score 0):

cp libthrift-0.9.2.jar /opt/app/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/lib/